# Jquery to fade in .after()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, jquery-after

Simple really but cannot get it to work, here is my script...

```
$('body').after('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + htmlHeight + 'px;"></div>');
```

How can I get it to fade in rather than just pop up? putting `fadeIn()` after or before `.after()` doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('body').after('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + htmlHeight + 'px; display:none;"></div>');
$('#lightBox').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body').after('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + htmlHeight + 'px;"></div>');  
$("#lightBox").hide().fadeIn();
```

It hides it and then fades in

Comment: Works perfectly, think I was overcomplicating things :p

Answer (score 2):

Short way:

```
$('body').after($('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + htmlHeight + 'px;"></div>').hide().fadeIn());
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.